# Raycasting against box geometry within it (three.js)

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to detect at which wall of the box geometry is the user looking at. Imagine that user is in a room and I want to detect which wall is the camera currently looking at. I'm raycasting from camera like this:

```
      var lookAtVector = new THREE.Vector3(0,0, -1);
      lookAtVector.applyQuaternion(camera.quaternion);

      raycaster.setFromCamera(lookAtVector, camera);
      var intersection = raycaster.intersectObject(box);
      console.log(intersection);
```

So this raycasting works fine outside the "room" but how to get it working inside the room?

Comment: Maybe you could reverse the ray

Comment: "It does not work" is not a proper problem description.

Comment: function `raycaster.intersectObject` returns an empty array instead of array of intersecting objects. Thus it does not find and intersection with the box although there certainly is one because the camera is inside of the box. Is that more understandable?

Comment: reversing the ray does'nt seem to help

Comment: I copy pasted you code into a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKZgeP?editors=0010) with a skybox and it seems to work for me (?)

Comment: posted an answer, raycaster.setFromCamera should only be used with a Vector2D representing mouse coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to remember is that the camera is always pointing in the negative z direction. When rotating and moving the camera, you are actualy rotating and moving the whole scene. Therefore I think there are two problems with you code.

I think you have to initialize your raycaster like this:

`var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, lookAtVector);`

<s>Where `lookAtVector` is just `var lookAtVector = new THREE.Vector3(0,0, -1);`, unmodified. This will send a ray from you camera's position in the direction it is facing.</s>

Then I think that maybe you are not rendering you box backside. When constructing your box material, pass along `side: THREE.BackSide` (or `THREE.DoubleSide`) as a parameter

**EDIT**

I was wrong about the lookAtVector. The ray is probably cast before the camera has modified the scene. Therefore you are absolutely right when applying the cameras quaternion on `lookAtVector`

Answer (score 0):

To raycast inside the box geometry you need to first make the inside of the box visible:

```
box.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
```

Or

```
box.material.side = THREE.BackSide;
```